# Math.round MAX returnable value

Tags: java

Am using Math.round and I am finding that it will not return me any value larger then (2^32/2)-1, but the documentation states it can/will return long values, i.e. 2^64... There a code snippet below.

```
long bTmp = (long)Math.round(4294967296L);
System.out.println(bTmp);
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

which output:

```
2147483647
9223372036854775807
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is calling the overload of `Math.round()` which takes a `float` and returns an `int`. See 
[the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)).

Try:

```
Math.round((double) 4294967296L)
```

Comment: Just to add some information on what is done: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2 By default there is a widening from long to float. To enforce the behaviour with double, it must be casted.